# Using insertAfter on a div with children freezes my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a JSfiddle I'm working with [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dalespiteri/ftd9gt3o/)

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $('.box').removeClass('active');
});

$('#bone').click(function () {
  $('#one').addClass('active');
  $('#one').insertAfter($('#container :last-child'))
});

$('#btwo').click(function () {
  $('#two').addClass('active');
  $('#two').insertAfter($('#container :last-child'))
});

$('#bthree').click(function () {
  $('#three').addClass('active');
  $('#three').insertAfter($('#container :last-child'))
});
```

What I'm trying to do is create an image slider in which when you select an image, it slides over top of the current top image. As you can see in the fiddle, it works fine. I'm getting the desired result by moving the selected div to the last child of the parent div to make it slide over top of the current top.

Where my problem is, is if I say put a paragraph, or another div, or any child element inside one of the divs I'm sliding, it will freeze my browser. I can only assume the moving of each div to be the last child is getting confused when the div I'm moving also has child elements... although I don't understand why that would break the code. It seems like my code is pretty straight forward in telling it to take the div containing the child elements, and moving it to the end of the list of children. It sounds complicated, but [here's a crude diagram of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PI3l.png).

Answer (score 0):

You should try appendTo instead of insertAfter, take a look at this one:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
  $('.box').removeClass('active');
});

$('#bone').click(function () {
  $('#one').addClass('active');
  $('#one').appendTo($('#container'))
});

$('#btwo').click(function () {
  $('#two').addClass('active');
  $('#two').appendTo($('#container'))
});

$('#bthree').click(function () {
  $('#three').addClass('active');
  $('#three').appendTo($('#container'))
});
```

```css
@keyframes slide {
  from {left: -100%;}
  to {left: 0%;}
}

#container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  display: block;
}

#one {
  background-color: red;
}

#two {
  background-color: blue;
}

#three {
  background-color: green;
}

.active {
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="bone">one</button><button id="btwo">two</button><button id="bthree">three</button>

<div id="container">
  
<div id="one" class="box">
  <p>
  Jagdish
  </p>
</div>
<div id="two" class="box"></div>
<div id="three" class="box"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Well that seems easy. I'll have to look into the difference between the two to figure out why one works and the other doesn't Thanks for the tip!